# directoryperDB is not working under WiredTiger storage Engine

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

When i enable the directoryperdb option  in the mongo.conf file, mongodb server service doesn't start.

```
2020-03-16T15:37:55.300+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'

2020-03-16T15:37:55.671+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] Trying to start Windows service 'MongoDB'

2020-03-16T15:37:55.672+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=8776 port=27017 dbpath=C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data 64-bit host=GGNUVBRESSCHINL

2020-03-16T15:37:55.672+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2

2020-03-16T15:37:55.672+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.0

2020-03-16T15:37:55.672+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a4b751dcf51dd249c5865812b390cfd1c0129c30

2020-03-16T15:37:55.672+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc

2020-03-16T15:37:55.672+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none

2020-03-16T15:37:55.672+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:

2020-03-16T15:37:55.672+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2012plus

2020-03-16T15:37:55.673+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64

2020-03-16T15:37:55.673+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64

2020-03-16T15:37:55.673+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\mongod.cfg", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, service: true, storage: { dbPath: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data", directoryPerDB: true, journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\log\mongod.log" } }

2020-03-16T15:37:55.674+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.

2020-03-16T15:37:55.674+0530 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: InvalidOptions: Requested option conflicts with current storage engine option for directoryPerDB; you requested true but the current server storage is already set to false and cannot be changed, terminating

2020-03-16T15:37:55.675+0530 I  NETWORK  [serviceStopWorker] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...

2020-03-16T15:37:55.675+0530 I  -        [serviceStopWorker] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.

2020-03-16T15:37:55.675+0530 I  CONTROL  [serviceStopWorker] now exiting
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have existing data files you cannot change settings which affect the layout of data on disk (like `directoryPerDB` or `directoryForIndexes`).

This is indicated in the error message in your startup log:

> InvalidOptions: Requested option conflicts with current storage engine option
>   for directoryPerDB; you requested true but the current server storage is
>   already set to false and cannot be changed, terminating

To change this option for existing deployments, you need to either `mongodump` and `mongorestore` your data (for a standalone deployment) or do a rolling upgrade via replication (for a replica set deployment).

See the [documentation for `diretoryPerDB`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.directoryPerDB) for steps on how to change this option for existing standalone or replica set deployments.